# MySql_workbench_import_, button

Tags: mysql

While importing data, the import start button is missing.

I saw that - someone written resolution should be minimal.

How can we do resolution on MySQL workbench?

Need- solution for resolution of MySQL workbench

Comment: It's a "visual bug". A workaround is to click on View > Panels > Hide Output Area. With that, the button should be visible.

Comment: Not working this trick